# I am creating a class that generate sql queries. Am I doing it right?

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a class (Datamap) that will help me simplify my queries in my model class. Basically, this class (Datamap) is use in conjunction with my db class.

Previously for an insert statement in my model I need.

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO test(id,name) VALUES("id","name")");
```

Now, with the Datamap class, it will be like

```
$datamap->create("test","id=id&name=name");
```

Below is snippet code from the Datamap class that I created.

```
    function create($tablename,$variables){
    $id=0;
    $tbl = $this->creturnval($variables);
    $tblVal = $tbl[0];
    $tblData = $tbl[1];
    $this->db->execute("INSERT into $tablename($tblVal) VALUES($tblData);");
    $id = $this->db->lastInsertedId();
    return $id;
}


function creturnval($variables){
    $vars = explode("&",$variables);
    $count = sizeOf($vars);
    $tblVal = "";
    $tblData = "";
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $d = explode("=",$vars[$i]);
        $tblVal.= $d[0].",";
        $tblData.= "'".$d[1]."'".",";
    }
    $tblVal = rtrim($tblVal, ',');
    $tblData = rtrim($tblData, ',');
    $return[0] = $tblVal;
    $return[1] = $tblData;
    return $return;
}
```

My concern is actually the performance issue. Previously in my model class, if I just used `$db->query()`, it seems to be faster because I do not have to go through 2 functions.

Now, in order to do an insert, I will need to parse the variables, split & etc, then process it.

My idea of using this Datamap class is actually to provide more maintainability and standardization. This is to prevent all my model classes from having sql statements over the place which looks untidy.

Do you think this will pose a possible performance issue?

PS: I am using my own framework that I build for my web application

Appreciate all advice.

Comment: Don't worry about performance. Only worry about performance when actually experience a performance issue.

Comment: @Frits, I wouldn't necessarily agree with that. You should always find the most efficient way to write your code the first time around.

Comment: The way you have written this wrapper completely negates any injection-prevention by PDO. Not a good idea.

Comment: Also, what if your column values contain an &? Use an array, not a string. That way, you don't need to parse it either.

Comment: if i were to use array and "clean" (prevent sql injection) the variables before executing the query, will using a sql wrapper be beneficial?

Comment: I am more of looking for a concept design advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a more common way of writting SQL wrappers is like this:

```
$item = $datamap->create("test");
$item->setValue("id", $id);
$item->setvalue("name", $name);
$item->update(); // push to database
```

`$datamap->create();` return an object that will hold the values for a record. `setValue` and `getValue` allow you to access it. `update` pushes new values to the database. Similarly, you could implement `$datamap->get("test", 1234);` where `1234` is the id of the record you want to fetch. `get` returns the same object as `create`, with the same functions. `update` will then cause an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`. After inserting a record using `update` you can use `mysql_last_insert_id()` to fetch the id and set it in the object so you can perform `UPDATE`s on it after that point. (The object has to keep track of it's 'state').

Answer (score 0):

After searching, i found out that it will be better to use Zend_db. will be using that.